# KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS doesn't correctly shape arabic numbers in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts, arabic-support

I am using [KFGQPC-uthmanic-script-hafs-regular](https://arabicfonts.net/fonts/kfgqpc-uthmanic-script-hafs-regular) to shape arabic numbers. I am following [Fonts in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts) to adapt custom font in my `Xamarin Forms` app. Font is working propertly in UWP (Windows 10), however, the same doesn't work in Android emulator. The shapes are presented differently from windows version. We can get arabic numbers (symbols) from [Arabic Numbers](http://allthearabicyouneverlearnedthefirsttimearound.com/p3/p3-ch3/arabic-numbers/).

e.g
[image: English and Arabic presentation of numbers]

Xamarin XAML

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label Text="١٢" FontFamily="Uthmanic" FontSize="50"/>
   <Label Text="١٧" FontFamily="Uthmanic" FontSize="50"/>
   <Label Text="١٩" FontFamily="Uthmanic" FontSize="50"/>
   <Label Text="٢٠٠" FontFamily="Uthmanic" FontSize="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Assembly file

```
[assembly: ExportFont("uthmanic.otf", Alias = "Uthmanic")]
```

Is there any workaround for this in Xamarin forms Android?

Comment: I test it in iOS and it works well as UWP. While in Android, it doesn't. Not sure if the problem is caused by the custom font or Xamarin.forms.

Comment: There are more different presentation in android for this font. I don't know if this xamarin custom bug for android.

Comment: You can open an issue in Github for more help. Or open a free Xamarin ticket [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6).